# How do i obtain a list of images/files from firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, firebase-storage

Hello I'm trying to get a list of images from the Firebase Bucket/Storage but I keep getting an error code when I call runApp(). Below is the code and the error message that corresponds to my problem. Any help would me much appreciated. I've tried doing what the error message recommended but I end up with a problem anyways.

```
import 'package:authorize_user/Screens/image_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Images',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: ImageScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ImageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getDocuments() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Accounts/ZqEbRkLFbW34CXKybmr7/images')
            .snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: getDocuments(),
        builder: (context, streamSnapshots) {
          if (streamSnapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          final documents = streamSnapshots.data.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: streamSnapshots.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Text(documents[index].data().length.toString()),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(child:Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {}),
    );
  }
}
```

**Error Message:**

> Exception has occurred. FlutterError (ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized. If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first. If you're running a test, you can call the `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` as the first line in your test's `main()` method to initialize the binding.)

Comment: Your code is querying Cloud Firestore.  It doesn't have "buckets".  Perhaps you are confusing it with Cloud Storage, which does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` before calling `Firebase.initializeApp();` in `main()`

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Hi there this doesn't work. I added both and it doesn't run.

Comment: What was the error you got?

Comment: Never mind I just had to restart my project. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

try this

```dart
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

> ref: https://github.com/TheAlphamerc/flutter_twitter_clone/blob/master/lib/main.dart

Comment: Hi there. I tried this and it still says Firebase.initializeApp()